# Segmentation fault 11 on boolean method

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to use a method to return 1 for true and 0 for false, but it gives me "Segmentation fault: 11" if it returns false. I've been janking my brain trying to figure out where I'm messing up but I can't seem to find anything.

Here's my code.

First the call to the function

```
int delete_number;
printf("Select a number to remove from list?\n");
scanf("%i", &delete_number);


if(remove_num(delete_number))
{
    printf("Deleted %i ", delete_number);
}
else
{
    printf("number %i not found in list", delete_number);
}
```

Now the function itself

```
int remove_num(int data) 
{
    int result = 0;
    node *curr_ptr;
    node *prev_ptr;
    node *temp_ptr;

    if(queuer.first != NULL)
    {
        if(queuer.first->data == data)
        {
            temp_ptr = queuer.first;
            queuer.first = queuer.first->next;

            if(queuer.first == NULL)
            {
                queuer.last = NULL;
            }

            free(temp_ptr);
            result = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            prev_ptr = queuer.first;
            curr_ptr = queuer.first->next;

            while(curr_ptr->data != data && curr_ptr != NULL)
            {
                prev_ptr = curr_ptr;
                curr_ptr = prev_ptr->next;
            }

            if(curr_ptr != NULL)
            {
                temp_ptr = curr_ptr;
                prev_ptr->next = temp_ptr->next;

                free(temp_ptr);
                result = 1;
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

I may have misunderstood the seg. fault but my thought was that this occurs because of how i run through the list with the while-loop. As I said, when the user inputs a number existing in the list, it works fine. When a number inputted is not in the list the seg.fault occurs.

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger? Oh, and the virtually obligatory link: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change:

```
        while(curr_ptr->data != data && curr_ptr != NULL)
```

to:

```
        while(curr_ptr != NULL && curr_ptr->data != data)
```

The tests in `&&` are executed left-to-right. You mustn't dereference `curr_ptr` until you've verified that it's valid.

Comment: Thank you. Basic knowledge that just slipped my mind, been staring at dark screens for too long.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try changing the condition in the while loop?

```
while(curr_ptr->data != data && curr_ptr != NULL)
{
    prev_ptr = curr_ptr;
    curr_ptr = prev_ptr->next;
}
```

It seems that you may be accessing the data (curr_ptr->data) when curr_ptr is NULL.